# Counting words in list using a dictionary

Tags: python, nlp

I have a list of dictionaries containing a word and some misspellings of the word. I am trying to go through a list of strings and first count the occurrences of the the word and then count the occurrences of each misspelling. I have tried using `if word in string` but this ends up giving me an incorrect count as many misspellings contain the actual word itself within them. Is it possible to use pythons `counter` here or would regex make more sense?

For example I have

```
words = [{'word':'achieve','misspellings':  ['acheive','acheiv','achiev']},

        {'word':'apparently','misspellings':['apparantly','apparintly']}]
```

I am looking to go through a list of strings and at the end have a total count of each word and its misspellings. I am having problems on misspellings like achiev which when using `if word in string` would count mess up the count because achiev in in achieve so the counts would be off.

Comment: You need to provide more context. Do you have code and samples of what you are trying? Expected output is help too.

Comment: Can you make an example of misspelled word that cause the double count?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: how are you deciding the misspellings?

Comment: Why not `misspellings = {'achieve': ['acheive','acheiv','achiev']}` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should map the misspelled words to the original:

```
words = {'acheive':'achieve', 'achiev':'achieve','achieve':'achieve'}

s = "achiev acheive achieve"

from collections import Counter

from string import punctuation

cn = Counter()
for word in s.split():
    word = word.strip(punctuation)
    if word in words:
        wrd = words[word]
        cn[wrd] += 1

print(cn)
Counter({'achieve': 3})
```

You can combine it with a regex to find all the words in the string instead of splitting as per 
[Tim Pietzcker's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30669300/2141635) answer.

To count the misspelled and original just check if the value returned from the words dict lookup is equal to the word, if so update the orig count for the word or else update the miss count:

```
words = {'acheive':'achieve', 'achiev':'achieve','achieve':'achieve',
         'apparently':'apparently','apparantly':'apparently','apparintly':'apparently'}


s = "achiev acheive achieve! 'apparently' apparintly 'apparantly?""

from collections import defaultdict
from string import punctuation

cn = defaultdict(lambda:{"orig": 0 ,"miss":0})
for word in s.split():
    word = word.strip(punctuation)
    if word in words:
        wrd = words[word]
        if wrd == word:
           cn[wrd]["orig"] += 1
        else:
            cn[wrd]["miss"] += 1
print(cn)
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x7f001fb2a8c0>, 
{'apparently': {'miss': 2, 'orig': 1}, 'achieve': {'miss': 2, 'orig': 1}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex probably is a good tool for this - [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) can help you avoid submatches within words.

For each word, build a regex using `wordre = re.compile(r"\b" + word + r"\b", re.I|re.U)` and then count the results of `re.findall(wordre, string)`.